# Can not get the timepicker value using Angular.js and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need one help. I am implementing `jquery.timepicker.js` to get the time interval in my Angular application but i am not getting any value like that.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
      <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">From Time :</span>
      <input type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="E.G-9.00AM" ng-model="time" ng-change="clearField('time');" maxlength="30" time-picker="" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
      <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">To Time :</span>
      <input type="text" name="time1" id="time1" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="E.G-9.00AM" ng-model="time1" ng-change="clearField('time1');" maxlength="30" time-picker="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center; padding:10px 0px;">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addTimeDetails();" id="saveData" value="Add" style="margin-right:20px;" />
  </div>
```

my controller side code is given below.

```
var app=angular.module('spesh',[]);
app.controller('formController',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.addTimeDetails=function(){
    console.log('time',$scope.time,$scope.time1);
  }
})
app.directive('timePicker', [function () {
        return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.timepicker();
            element.on('changeTime', function () {
              $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.model = element.val();
              });
            });

        }
    }
}]);
```

Here i need when user will click on text field the time drop down will come and click on add button the selected time will show in console.MY complete code is [here in plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7uynLm3eQOQNGhF5CqbY?p=preview).Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<html ng-model="spesh">` to `<html ng-app="spesh">`

Here is better solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/A0sSqXzx73XYn0f7UVGD?p=preview

When you require ngModel, you can use it's methods or read value. You don't need to read ngModel attribute.

> **$setViewValue(value, trigger);** Update the view value.
>
> This method should be called when a control wants to change the view
>   value; typically, this is done from within a DOM event handler. For
>   example, the input directive calls it when the value of the input
>   changes and select calls it when an option is selected.

Comment: Well, mark it as answer than or delete a question. :)